# Reference database column with variable in sequel sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, crud, erb, sequel

How do I refernce the column in the database with the column variable in the url/route. The column varible is a string coming from a webpage, and I have to reference the column with a hash key.

Sinatra route:

```
get '/users/update/:id/:column/:value' do
  User.where(id: params[:id]).update(column: params[:value])
  redirect back
end
```

Html:

```
<a href="/users/update/<%= user.id %>/status/3">Value</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to use `params[:column]` as a variable key in the update you can use the hash rocket syntax:

`User.where(id: params[:id]).update(params[:column] => params[:value])`